Integrating Webmidi.js and p5.js
I am wondering how to integrate integrate Webmidi.js, p5.js, and my Akai mPK49 midi controller? This is for a final project for school.
Reading through the Webmidi.js Basics, I was able to get the program to "listed" to my midi controller. Even though the p5 website was throwing a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')" error, the note names were printing in the console. I then tried to see if I could play midi notes in my DAW Logic Pro X. I noticed that both logic and the P5.js/Webmidi.js program were both acknowledging that I was playing keys on the controller.
I went on to the next step to add a basic synth and to try to play an actual note. The console stopped showing that I was playing notes and only showed the Akai ports and that Logic Pro was an input and output.
Additionally, I commented out new lines of code for the synth and the console still would not show the midi notes in the console. So I am a bit stumped. Here is a link to the P5.js sketch. Any help is appreciated!
  function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  WebMidi
  .enable()
  //.then(() => console.log("WebMidi enabled!"))
  .then(onEnabled)
  .catch(err => alert(err));
  
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
 
}
function onEnabled() {

  // Inputs
  WebMidi.inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.manufacturer, input.name));
  
  // Outputs
  WebMidi.outputs.forEach(output => console.log(output.manufacturer, output.name));

   const myInput = WebMidi.getInputByName("Akai MPK 49");
   const mySynth = myInput.channels[1]; // <-- the MIDI channel (10)
  
  myInput.addListener("noteon", e => {
  console.log(e.note.identifier);
    })
  
  mySynth.addListener("noteon", e => {
  console.log(e.note.identifier, e.message.channel);
})
  
  let output = WebMidi.outputs[0];
let channel = output.channels[1];
channel.playNote("C3");
}


Please fix your code [![enter image description here] mistake. Thanks.

@K-PopCorn it could be that WebMidi.getInputByName("Akai MPK 49") fails (potentially device disconnected, typo in name, etc.). and myInput is undefined, therefore accessing channels would fail. Haven't tried WebMidi before, but try to console.log(WebMidi.inputs) before calling getInputByName and double check the name/id. (also try WebMidi.getInputById with the right Id instead of getInputByName just in case).

The following works on my system. p5.TriOsc() is used to play the notes with this technique.  You will need to change the name for your device; you don't need the manufacturer, only the device name. You will also need to add the following script to index.html:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/webmidi@latest/dist/iife/webmidi.iife.js"></script>

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  osc = new p5.TriOsc(); // Need this to play the notes
  env = new p5.Envelope();
  WebMidi.enable()
    .then(() => console.log("WebMidi enabled!"))
    .then(onEnabled)
    .catch((err) => alert(err));
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}

function playSound(midiVal) {
  osc.start();
  freq = midiToFreq(midiVal);
  osc.freq(freq);
  env.ramp(osc, 0, 1.0, 0);
}

function onEnabled() {
  // Inputs
  WebMidi.inputs.forEach((input) =>
    console.log(input.manufacturer, input.name)
  );

  // Outputs
  WebMidi.outputs.forEach((output) =>
    console.log(output.manufacturer, output.name)
  );

  const myInput = WebMidi.getInputByName("Q Mini");

  myInput.addListener("noteon", (e) => {
    console.log(e.note.identifier);
    console.log("value =", e.message.data[1]);
    playSound(e.message.data[1]);
  });
}


Alternate Method:
The following is an alternate method which does not require any additional code to be added to index.html or a 'listener' to be requested.  Its shortcoming is that onmidimessage is reported twice and therefore the note is played twice.  To work around this issue a counter is added and reset to zero after the first iteration, thereby playing the note only once.
let counter = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100);
  osc = new p5.TriOsc(); // Need this to play the notes
  env = new p5.Envelope();
}

function playSound(midiVal) {
  osc.start();
  freq = midiToFreq(midiVal);
  osc.freq(freq);
  env.ramp(osc, 0, 1.0, 0);
}

navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then((midiAccess) => {
  console.log(midiAccess.inputs);
  Array.from(midiAccess.inputs).forEach((input) => {
    input[1].onmidimessage = (msg) => {
      if (counter == 0) {
        console.log("value =", msg.data[1]);
        playSound(msg.data[1]);
      }
      counter++;
      if (counter > 1) counter = 0;
    };
  });
});

function draw() {
  background(220);
}



Thank you for your advice. I gave your code a shot. I keep getting thrown the following error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener')" I assumed assListener was a part of the library. I tried to create an addListener variable but without any success.

Should run without error. Did you add the webmidi library shown above to index.html?  I've seen an error message like that when trying to use a function before the class has been called.  Copy/paste the code 'as is' into the p5.js web editor; don't try to rearrange it.  I ran it in a Chrome browser.

I tried it again and made sure to put the link above in the html again and it still throws and error. But the error is in the form of a pop up. it does not show an error in the console. The program is recognizing my keyboard and if I open up Logic Pro it even recognizes Logic as an output. But it is not recognizing when I am pressing any keys. At one point it was recognizing the keys yesterday and then all of a sudden it just stopped and I am so stumped. Thank you for your help!

Do you see the note and its value in the console?  In order to play a note you need the value from each key.  If you don't see the note's letter and its value then the WebMidi listener is not working for some reason.  I have also been unsuccessful at using the playNote() function that you initially posted.  Is there another Midi app that you could try?  Here is another reference if you haven't seen it: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/03/web-midi-api/

Please try the second method in the edited answer.
